# Javascript and Jquery: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Currently I'm writing a site where one feature is to allow the user to type in the name of a card (the game's Hearthstone), and add it to a deck on the site. I'm using JSON data from 
http://hearthstonejson.com/json/AllSets.json , but I'm having trouble querying that data.

Right now I have:

```
// On user submission, searches for the inputted card name and places it into
// the deck if a match is found
$("#cardSearch").submit(function(){   
    card = $("#userInput").val();
    console.log("Card searched: " + card);
    $.getJSON("http://hearthstonejson.com/json/AllSets.json",function(cards){
       // cards = JSON.parse(cards);
        console.log(cards);
        $.each(cards.name, function(key, val){ 
            if (val.name == card) {
                console.log("Success, I found :" + val.name);
                return;
            }
        });   
    }   
    );
});
```

My error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined , referencing line 631 from the latest version of jquery.

I thought that maybe I had to parse the data, as you can see with the commented line of code in the middle. But, when I add that line, I get a different error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o.

I'm not sure where to proceed.

Thanks for the help - I'm pretty new to this!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $.each(cards, function(key, val) instead?

Comment: Try defining "cards" as an array in the beginning of your code, then see if it still gives "can't find length of undefined"

Comment: In console, where you get your error, you should be able to expand it so the full stacktrace is shown. find the closest place that is outside jQuery and inside your own code; that will be the place you need to look at.

Comment: @KennyC Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var card = $("#userInput").val();
$.getJSON("http://hearthstonejson.com/json/AllSets.json", function (cards) {
    //Returns a JSON object where cards are grouped into something like this Basic, Credits, Debug etc
    //Each of these groups contains an array of cards
    //So the first step is to loop through the groups and inside this loop through the array of cards.
    $.each(cards, function (key, val) {
        //Here val is an array of cards
        //In order to get each card we have loop through val.
        $.each(val, function (index, data) {
            //Here data is refferd to as individual card
            if (data.name == card) {
                console.log("Success, I found :" + data.name);
                return;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

JSON cards:

```
Object {Basic: Array[212], Credits: Array[17], Debug: Array[39], Expert: Array[392], Missions: Array[37]…}
```

We have to use `cards.Basic[index]` to get a particular card

```
Object {id: "GAME_004", name: "AFK", type: "Enchantment", text: "Your turns are shorter."}
```

Here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jQNAz/)**

Comment: Ahh, someone who has actually looked at the detailed structure of the JSON that this API returns.

Comment: You should probably explain why you have the nested loops, perhaps show an excerpt of the JSON to justify it.

Answer (score 0):

The error means $.each could not access the object as an array which means it does not have the length property.

Your code should be:

```
$.each(cards, function(key, val)
```